# Fenics: time-independent Sine-Gordon equation

Tags: finite-element, fenics, nonlinear-equations

Is there a code for the equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} = \sin(u)
$$
or for the sine gordon equation in two dimensions because I want to change some boundary values to see the results?

Comment: Hi @jessie, welcome to scicomp! The $\theta$-notation is a little weird, but other than that this looks very much like the Poisson equation -- *the* basic starting example for many numerical methods. Check out http://fenicsproject.org/documentation/dolfin/1.2.0/python/demo/pde/poisson/python/documentation.html.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to change the $\theta$ to $\partial$ according to standard notation, because I assumed that was just to avoid MathJax. Feel free to change back if that was incorrect.

Comment: Actually, it's not the Poisson equation since it's not linear in $u$ (it appears in the $\sin$ on the right-hand side).

Comment: @ChristianClason: Yes, but corresponding fixed point iteration $\Delta u_{n+1} = \sin(u_n)$ is Poisson equation - I don't say whether it converges or not. Similiarly applying Newton method would result in reaction-diffusion equation.

Answer (score 5):

That's actually very easy to do in Dolfin:

```py
from dolfin import *
# define mesh, function space (piecewise linear)
mesh = UnitSquareMesh(64,64)
V = FunctionSpace(mesh,'CG',1)
# inhomogeneous boundary conditions (otherwise the solution is trivial)
bc = DirichletBC(V, Constant(1.0), lambda x,on_boundary: on_boundary)
# define bi(non)linear form
# note that nonlinear problems need u to be a Function, not TestFunction
u = Function(V)
v = TestFunction(V)
F = inner(grad(u),grad(v))*dx + sin(u)*v*dx
# solve using Newton method (Jacobian is computed automatically)
solve(F==0,u,bc)
plot(u,interactive=True)
```

There is also a `nonlinear-poisson` demo in the `demo/undocumented` directory, which also shows how to enter define more complicated nonlinear forms and thow to control the solver parameters.

Comment: You forgot minus from integration by parts.

Comment: @Jan - right, fixed now!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I can't understand the lambda x as a boundary condition.

Comment: That just defines an anonymous function that returns `True` if the point `x` lies on the boundary; such a function (or a class implementing this function) is how FEniCS expects the part of the boundary where the condition should be imposed to be specified.

Comment: @jessie: `lambda` is python keyword - see http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda for description.

Comment: If the equation had this form \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} = \sin(u)*f(x,y)
where f(x,y) a function which is 0 for some boundary conditions and 1 else. How can i define this in fenics for the function f(x,y)?

Comment: @jessie - What you're asking doesn't make sense, since the equation holds on the *interior* of the domain. Boundary conditions have to be specified separately. You should ask this as a new question (use the link `ask your own question`), and give a bit more detail about what you're trying to do (i.e., the mathematical or application background - it's very hard to give a good answer without knowing the background).

Comment: Thanks Christian for your quick responses.I would like to add a function f(x,y) at this point of the equation =sin(u)*f(x,y) where f takes two values 0,1.For 1 the equation holds on the interior of subdomain and for 0 in another subdomain.

Comment: When f(x,y) = 0, we will have this equation ∂^2u/∂x^2+∂^2u∂y^2=0